# Is there a way to Sum SQLFunction.DateDiff inside a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have to summarize data from services, according to logged user. So far I've got to this:

```
SummaryModel q = (from s in pe.Services
    join g in pe.Groups on s.GroupId equals g.GroupId
    join ud in pe.UserDetails on s.UserIdInCharge equals ud.UserId into ud1
        from ud in ud1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where allowedGroups.Contains(g.GroupId)
        && (!filterBySector || filter.selectedSectors.Contains(g.GroupId))
        && (!filterByGroup || (s.UserIdInCharge.HasValue 
                               && members.Contains(s.UserIdInCharge.Value)))
        && (s.Status == (decimal)Data.Enums.ServiceStatus.Active 
            || s.Status == (decimal)Data.Enums.ServiceStatus.Sold)
        && s.ServiceStartDate >= startDate
        && s.ServiceStartDate <= endDate
        group s by new Guid() into services
        select new SummaryModel()
          { 
            Holes = services.Where(ss => ss.UserIdInCharge == null).Count(),
            Candidates = services.Sum(ss => ss.ServiceApplies.Count()),
            Announced = services.Where(ss => ss.AnnouncementType != 0).Count(),
            TotalServices = services.Count(),
            TotalHours = (decimal)services.Sum(ss => SqlFunctions
                      .DateDiff("hh", ss.ServiceStartDate, ss.ServiceEndDate)),
           TotalBudget = services.Sum(ss => ss.Value.Value),
          }).SingleOrDefault();
```

But the line below returns:

```
TotalHours = (decimal)services.Sum(ss => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("hh",
                                   ss.ServiceStartDate, ss.ServiceEndDate)),
```

**ERROR**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiff(System.String,
>   System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],
>   System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])', method, which does not can be converted to an 
>   expression of repository.

**Date samples**

- StartDate => 05/09/2011 23:00:00
- EndDate => 06/09/2011 11:00:00

Any alternatives?

Comment: That is one very large linq statement.

Comment: pull it into your application by using ToArray() or ToList() and then sum it

Comment: @reggaeguitar Service is a big entity and if I do that it will be loading many unused data, and we don't want that, right?

Comment: In your query just select the ServiceStartDate and ServiceEndDate, then after the query is in your application do the summing of the date differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what happened is that VS was using `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions` instead `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions`. I forced the namespace so LINQ could find the right set of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
var timeDifArray = (from s in pe.Services
    join g in pe.Groups on s.GroupId equals g.GroupId
    join ud in pe.UserDetails on s.UserIdInCharge equals ud.UserId into ud1
        from ud in ud1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where allowedGroups.Contains(g.GroupId)
        && (!filterBySector || filter.selectedSectors.Contains(g.GroupId))
        && (!filterByGroup || (s.UserIdInCharge.HasValue 
                               && members.Contains(s.UserIdInCharge.Value)))
        && (s.Status == (decimal)Data.Enums.ServiceStatus.Active 
            || s.Status == (decimal)Data.Enums.ServiceStatus.Sold)
        && s.ServiceStartDate >= startDate
        && s.ServiceStartDate <= endDate
        group s by new Guid() into services
        select new
          { 
            services.ServiceStartDate,
            services.ServiceEndDate,
          }).ToArray();

var timeDifs = timeDifArray.Select(x => x.ServiceEndDate.Subtract(x.ServiceEndDate));
var totalTimeDifs = timDifs.Sum(x => x.Hours);
```